# How to write code for counts prices from checked inputs

Tags: javascript, input, count, price

I started to learn javascript 2 weeks ago. I want to do my first program which counts all prices from checked input.

But i dont have idea how to do this.

I found something on internet and stackoverflow, but i dont know to do this for my inputs.

Could you help me?

[My code](https://codepen.io/soorta/pen/dawgJe)

```
// this function counts all the values
function showPrice() {
    var priceOne = document.getElementsByName('price1');
    var priceTwo = document.getElementsByName('price2');
    var priceThree = document.getElementsByName('price3');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by getting a list of elements for all the inputs, check the ones that are checked, get their values, convert them to numbers and sum them.

1. Beginning with a list of ids, use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the list into a list of string ids (`1 -> test1`).
2. Then apply [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to each id to get the HTML element.
3. Then from the element extract and convert the value if the input is checked, otherwise map the element to 0.
4. Use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the values.
5. Using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), find your output span and set its `innerHTML` to the total.

```js
function showPrice() {
  const total = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    .map(id => `test${id}`)
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id))
    .map(el => el && el.checked ? Number(el.value) : 0)
    .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);

  document.getElementById('getPrice').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```css
.priceInput {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.priceOutput {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceInput">
<p>Part 1</p>
<label for="test1">test1</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test1" value="10">
<label for="test2">test2</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test2" value="25">
<label for="test3">test3</label>
<input type="radio" name="price1" id="test3" value="12">
</div>
    
<div class="priceInput">    
<p>Part 2</p>    
<label for="test4">test4</label>
<input type="radio" name="price2" id="test4" value="5">
<label for="test5">test5</label>
<input type="radio" name="price2" id="test5" value="7">
<label for="test6">test6</label>
<input type="radio" name="price2" id="test6" value="2">
</div>
    
<div class="priceInput">   
<p>Part 3</p>    
<label for="test7">test7</label>
<input type="radio" name="price3" id="test7" value="250">
<label for="test8">test8</label>
<input type="radio" name="price3" id="test8" value="720">
<label for="test9">test9</label>
<input type="radio" name="price3" id="test9" value="410">
</div>
<br>
<div class="priceOutput">
  <button onclick="showPrice()">Show Price</button>
  <p>Your Price is : <span id="getPrice">0<!--Here i want to get price1(value) + price2(value) + price3(value)--></span> $</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for quick answer. Your code work 100%. But i dont understand this : .map(id => `test${id}`) and this .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0). I go learn someting about array.map and reduce.

Comment: The test${id} thing is a template string, it allows you to inject variable into a string, I added some links for reduce and map

Comment: Hi, i tried to understand it but i can not :/ maybe i will not be so good developer like you, but i tried to make my own code. Can you check if is it ok? I know that it's working but if is it correctly writen.

Comment: Hello i found what does it mean .map(id => `test${id}`) ......please repair me if not .map(id => 'test' + (id)). But i still dont know to understand this .map(el => el && el.checked ? Number(el.value) : 0)

Comment: is it ?  if(el => el && el.checked){
  .map(Number(el.value))}
  else .map(0)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, it seems that you want to get the option the user selected out of the radio buttons and not all radio buttons (referring to the [getElementsByName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)). To do so, you can go over the nodeList returned and see if any of the elements have the checked property.

```
for(let i = 0; i < priceOne.length; i++){
   if(priceOne[i].checked) {
     //Get value of the price selected with .value
     let priceOneValue = priceOne[i].value;
   }
}
```

After doing this for all your input types, you can sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

JO_VA here is my own code. Can you check it? It's easier for my understanding.

I found just 1 problem and it is : when i remove from HTML input tag "checked" and i klikn only for 1 or 2 radio options, it show NaN in paragraph for price.

BTW sorry for my english (i ussually dont use english language)

```
function showPrice(){
var pricePlace = document.getElementById("getPrice");
getVal1();
getVal2();
getVal3();
var InputNumber = Number(inputVal1) + Number(inputVal2) + Number(inputVal3);
pricePlace.innerHTML = InputNumber;
}
var inputVal1;
function getVal1(){
var a = document.getElementById("test1");
var b = document.getElementById("test2");
var c = document.getElementById("test3");
if (c.checked) {
    inputVal1 = c.value;
}
if (b.checked) {
    inputVal1 = b.value;
}
if (a.checked) {
    inputVal1 = a.value;
}
} 
var inputVal2;
function getVal2(){
var a = document.getElementById("test4");
var b = document.getElementById("test5");
var c = document.getElementById("test6");
if (c.checked) {
    inputVal2 = c.value;
}
if (b.checked) {
    inputVal2 = b.value;
}
if (a.checked) {
    inputVal2 = a.value;
}
}
var inputVal3;
function getVal3(){
var a = document.getElementById("test7");
var b = document.getElementById("test8");
var c = document.getElementById("test9");
if (c.checked) {
    inputVal3 = c.value;
}
if (b.checked) {
    inputVal3 = b.value;
}
if (a.checked) {
    inputVal3 = a.value;
}
}
```

Or you can check it in https://codepen.io/soorta/pen/gqEGyQ